# Page load with logo fadein

Tags: jquery, load, fadein, fade, effect

I don't know how to explain the type of effect I want but I'll try to be simple.
I would like my home page to be opened with my logo in the middle of the screen on a white background and a few seconds later the logo is fading and it shows the home page.

I thought about an index.php with what I want and after 5 seconds it redirects on a index2 with my full homepage but this is definitely not good for the SEO.
So maybe with the help of JQuery I could get what I want.

I thought about changing that code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$('#page_effect').fadeIn(2000);
});
```

But how could I get the logo in the middle etc...

Thank you very much for your help, 
Cordially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the rest of the page content in a `<div>`, and have the logo fade out and the `<div>` containing the page content fade in.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/dzghq2bc/1/)

Comment: Fascinating ! I did not think it was that simple! Thank you very much Sir! Just, do this have an impact on the SEO ?

Comment: No, it will not affect that at all.